# Value for text alignment in style.xml for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to create set of TextView programmatically but a want to customize each TextView by xml style. I create TextView instances and place it into LinearLayout.
In my style.xml script I add  custom values for text size and color, and all work fine.
But I cant't set text alignment to center by my styles.xml file.

It's my java code snippet:

```
import android.view.View;

public class GramophoneForm extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private LinearLayout m_button_container = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....
        ....
        m_button_container = this.findViewById(R.id.gr_view_container);

        List<? extends Object> ct_list = getClassificationTypes();
        setObjectsList(ct_list);
    }

    public void setObjectsList(List<? extends Object> objects)
    {
        m_button_container.removeAllViews();

        for(Object o : objects)
        {
            TextView item = new TextView(this);            
            item.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.selectionTextStyle);
////////////////////Is't works fine, but I want set up text alignment by xml style
            item.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
////////////////////
            item.setText(o.toString());
            item.setTag(o);

            m_button_container.addView(item);
        }
    }
}
```

My styles.xml code snippet:

```
<style name="selectionTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
 <!-- don't work  -->
    <item name="android:layout_centerInParent">true</item>
<!-- don't work
    <item name="android:textAlignment">4</item>
 -->
<!--don't work
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
 -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for your problem is to create a XML layout with a TextView with the style applied to it, and instead of creating an instance of TextView every time, inflate the layout.

XML example, lets say its named myTextViewLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/selectionTextStyle" />
```

And in your for loop inflate it and add it to the container:

```
for(Object o : objects){
    TextView item = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myTextViewLayout, null);          
    item.setText(o.toString());
    item.setTag(o);

    m_button_container.addView(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should insert a dimension value within the style xml:

```
<dimen name="buttonHeight">40px</dimen>
```

Then you simply should reference the dimension value. So in your layout file you'll write:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
```

Answer (score 0):

change your parent attribute from this `parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView"` to this `android:Widget.Material.Light.TextView` hope it will work!

Comment: I can't use it because I use API level 17

Comment: Increase it why you are using such a low level api?

Comment: I want my app runnable at 98 % devices

Comment: If you make on API 19,your app will also available on 98% devices. Try it..

Comment: Android Studio talk me that for it I need API level 21:     android:Widget.Material.Light.TextView requires API level 21 (current min is 17). But building are ends successful, of couse